# Unselect all checkboxes on button click when jquery.multiselect.js is used

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I'm using **jquery.mutiselect.js** to implement the functionality of selecting multiple things from dropdown menu in the form of checkboxes.
All the things are working fine, except now I want to deselect all the things i.e uncheck all the checkboxes, clear the input textbox as it was before when nothing was selected on a button click.

I've referred to one answer:

```js
var all_checkboxes = jQuery(':checkbox');
all_checkboxes.prop('checked',false);
```

```html
<link href="~/Content/jquery.multiselect.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<script src="~/Scripts/jquery.multiselect.js"></script>
```

But this doesn't work properly. It unchecks the checkboxes, but when I see me Html, it still shows selected and it doesn't clears out the text as well from the textbox.

The jquery behind it is a little bit complicated to understand as it appends all the classes like "ms-options", "data-search-term , ms-options-wrap ms-has-selections etc.
Can anyone help me out with this or should I provide my html code in detail in the edit?

Comment: @Ashwin Kumar, I've referenced <link href="~/Content/jquery.multiselect.css" rel="stylesheet" />
                         <script src="~/Scripts/jquery.multiselect.js"></script> in my html

Comment: Can you provide your html and javascript code?

Comment: After changing the property I guess you have to do a refresh: $('#your-select').multiSelect('refresh');